# javascript error that says array.some is not a function

Tags: javascript

[image][image]I am not sure why I keep getting this error that says "array.some is not a function". I apply the same logic in another part of the file and it works with no issue. I am simply trying to check the array to see if a specific ID exists, if it does--to console.log the roleId.

```js
var match='222';
getMyEnrollments() {
  var vm = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: "",
    type: 'Get',
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      array=data;
    
      if (array.some(array => array.OrgUnit.Id === match)) {
           console.log("Object found");
      } 
      else {
        console.log("Object not found in the enrollments.");
      }
     
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: `array` likely is not an array when you call `.some()` on it. Since your snippet does not reproduce the issue, it's hard to say what's wrong. Debug and look at what the `array` value is set to when calling upon it.

Comment: You're essentially redeclaring `array`. You have a variable `array` that you assign data to (which is unnecessary here), and then using the same variable `array` in the `some` callback

Comment: if `array.some()` is not a function, then `array` is probably not an array ...

Comment: @Phix while that may be quite bad style, it's perfectly valid to do so ...

Comment: @derpirscher please see screenshot of data I get when I console.log.

Comment: Could you swap `console.log(data);` for `console.log(Array.isArray(data));` ?

Comment: @BenStephens I get a false

Comment: Well, then `array` is not an array. It might look like one, but it isn't ... Could be deserialized from something like `{"0": {...}, "1": {...}, "2": {...} }`.

Comment: Try changing `array=data;` to `array=Object.values(data);`

Comment: I still get false, but now the error says "cannot read property 'Id' of undefined

Comment: so I just stringified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think setting array to `data.Items` should do the trick:

```js
const data = {
  PagingInfo: { "Bookmark": "6796", "HasMoreItems": true },
  "Items": [
    { OrgUnit: { Id: 2234 } },
    { OrgUnit: { Id: 2244 } },
    { OrgUnit: { Id: 2245 } },
    { OrgUnit: { Id: 222 } },
  ]
};

let array = data.Items;

let match = '222';

if (array.some(array => array.OrgUnit.Id === parseInt(match))) {
  console.log("Match found for " + match);
} else {
  console.log("Match not found for " + match);
}

match = '223';

if (array.some(array => array.OrgUnit.Id === parseInt(match))) {
  console.log("Match found for " + match);
} else {
  console.log("Match not found for " + match);
}
```

Could some of the values be missing an OrgUnit?

Comment: can you see the additional screenshot. Array is inside of Array..if that could be the issue?

Comment: @Vzupo that seems likely, what does data look like fully without Object.values() applied? Perhaps `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));`

Comment: {
t"PagingInfo": {
tt"Bookmark": "6796",
tt"HasMoreItems": true
t},
t"Items": [
tt{
ttt"OrgUnit": {
tttt"Id": 6606,
tttt"Type": {
ttttt"Id": 1,
ttttt"Code": "Organization",
ttttt"Name": "Organization"
tttt},
tttt"Name": "a test location",
tttt"Code": "ABC"
ttt},
ttt"Role": {
tttt"Id": 106,
tttt"Code": null,
tttt"Name": "Administrator"
ttt}
tt},

Comment: @Vzupo I've edited my answer for this data structure.